# Why is there no Seed method to override in my Migration class in C# EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hello I'm receiving no suitable method found to override when writing this code

protected override void Seed(MuziekApp.MuziekContext context)  { }

How come I don't have a Seed method to override in my migration? What am I exactly missing or doing wrong?

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MuziekApp.Migrations
{
    public partial class Second : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {

        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {

        }

        protected override void Seed(MuziekApp.MuziekContext context)
        {

            List<Artiest> lijst = new List<Artiest>()
            {
                new Artiest() { ArtiestID = 1, Naam = "Jane", InstrumentID = 1, InstrumentNaam = "Saxofoon", PopgroepID = 1, GroepNaam = "Killers"},
                new Artiest() { ArtiestID = 2, Naam = "Charles", InstrumentID = 2, InstrumentNaam = "Gitaar", PopgroepID = 1, GroepNaam = "Killers"},
                new Artiest() { ArtiestID = 3, Naam = "Miguel", InstrumentID = 1, InstrumentNaam = "Saxofoon", PopgroepID = 2, GroepNaam = "Rock"},
                new Artiest() { ArtiestID = 4, Naam = "John", InstrumentID = 2, InstrumentNaam = "Gitaar", PopgroepID = 2, GroepNaam = "Rock" }
             };

            List<Instrument> lijst2 = new List<Instrument>()
            {
                new Instrument() {  InstrumentID = 1, InstrumentNaam = "Saxofoon"},
                new Instrument() {  InstrumentID = 2, InstrumentNaam = "Gitaar"}
             };

            List<Popgroep> lijst3 = new List<Popgroep>()
            {
                new Popgroep() { PopgroepID = 1, GroepNaam = "Killers"},
                new Popgroep() { PopgroepID = 2, GroepNaam = "Rock"}
             };

            context.Artiesten.AddRange(lijst);
            context.Instrumenten.AddRange(lijst2);
            context.Popgroepen.AddRange(lijst3);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: EF Core doesn't have a seed method.

Comment: Doesn't look like `Migration` has a `Seed` method according to the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migration

Comment: Where can I use the seed method then?

Comment: use Sql() in your migrations

Comment: Could you provide an example on how to use Sql within the migrations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Sql() in your migration file

```
Sql("INSERT INTO Artiests (Name, InstrumentID) VALUES ('Jane', 1)");
```

It just allows you to use SQL statements for seeding. You would want to seed data like your instruments first so the ID was valid for your FK. Just consider the order you put them in.

Comment: In which method does this belong

Comment: Changes would go in the `Up()`. If you want to do changes on a downgrade you can put those in `Down()`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not needed since `OnModelCreating` [can simply do the job for you or you can modify the migration logic to add seeding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding).